# Android sdk textview

Tags: android, textview

---

Hello . I have a question. Can anyone explain how can I do one thing in android sdk?
On different devices, I have different `textview`s.  For example, on a device with 3.7 display
I have normal letters, but on 7 display I have so little letters. How can I make letters normal on all displays? Please provide some examples.

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lineage2m"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1m"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/m1"
        android:textColor="@color/hz"
        android:textSize="15pt" />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1m"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/m2"
        android:textColor="@color/hz"
        android:textSize="15pt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1m"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/m3"
        android:textColor="@color/hz"
        android:textSize="15pt" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1m"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/m4"
        android:textColor="@color/hz"
        android:textSize="15pt" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The documentation has a whole article about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 3):

Android uses SP for scaled font sizes (e.g. use 15sp instead of 15pt), DP is for pixels. If the layout needs to be completely different for different screen densities you can also create a unique layout for each one:

e.g.

\res\layout\(default layouts go here)

\res\layout-hdpi\(high dpi layouts go here)

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "15pt" with "15sp" (or "15dp", I have to look up what's the exact different)
Then the used font size used will be dependent on the dpi (dots per inch) of the device.